# Is it possible to separate a learnable function $f(x)$ to the integration of an unlearnable part and a learnable part?

Tags: machine-learning, computational-learning-theory

For a general learnable function $f(x)$, is it possible to construct a function $h(x)$

s.t. $x \rightarrow h(x)$ is unlearnable or very hard to learn, while $h(x) \rightarrow f(x)$ is learnable?

Any theoretical results or concrete construction is highly appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

In general it's difficult to pin down a *truly* unlearnable function especially in the context of deep learning. And for hard to learn functions, I suppose you mean complex nonlinear functions, discontinuous functions, non-differentiable function which hinder gradient based optimizations. Under such assumptions, [transfer learning](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Transfer_learning) could be such a concrete ML technique to extract features from some existing model which is hard to learn such as GPT and try to learn a relatively easier and related downstream task by fine tuning, usually:

> For example, for image classification, knowledge gained while learning to recognize cars could be applied when trying to recognize trucks.

Comment: Thank you for the helpful answer. However, I can't quite get why transfer learning can be applied here. I think transfer learning means that, we can separate a "hard to learn" function to a "hard to learn" function and an "easy to learn" function. Here the target is separating an "easy to learn" function to a "hard to learn" one and an "easy to learn" one. Although they are similar, but I can't really get how they can be connected together.

Comment: @Marc_12 You only specified "For a general learnable function f(x)" which should be regarded as hard imo. If you already know a priori f(x) is easy, then why you need to decompose it into a hard component in the first place?

Comment: Sorry for the confusion. I'm just wondering whether there is a magic function that is very hard to learn, but relatively easy to learn from.

Comment: @Marc_12 Then GPT neural network as universal approximated function with billions of parameters is certainly hard to learn in almost every aspect such as money, hardware resources, time, intellectual effort, but relatively easy to learn from such as via ChatGPT anyone can try to solicit their own prompted answer which is your 2nd step h(x)→f(x).

Answer (score 0):

well say $x$ are the initial conditions of a double pendulum, and $h(x)$ is  a model of the differential equation that governs it... learning it will be very hard, because it's a chaotic system, but if you set $f$ being "does the pendolum exist", well the answer is yes always, so you can definitely learn it

Comment: Thank you for your helpful answer. I'm wondering whether or not there exists a more general "hard to learn" function that can be applied on input of a general ML model, while still enjoying the property. Thanks!